# Postgres cast to UUID from JSON

Tags: postgresql

I have two very simple tables `sessions` which has a `json` column like this:

```
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+
| id |                         data                          |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | { "user_id": "bc2166dd-ca1d-41c6-9c66-610f844ca139" } |
+----+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

And also a `users` table like this:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
|                  id                  |       email        |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
| bc2166dd-ca1d-41c6-9c66-610f844ca139 | foobar@example.com |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+
```

Is there a way to join on the contents of the `json` column type like this?

```
with recursive active_sessions AS (
  select
  data->'users_id' as sid
  from sessions
)

select *
from active_sessions
join users ON active_sessions.sid = users.id
where sid is not null;
```

In my basic attempts, I'm stuck and cannot seem to get the json text to be able to be used in a join, I get this error:

```
[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for uuid: ""bc2166dd-ca1d-41c6-9c66-610f844ca139""
```

**note the double quotes...?**

I've also tried casting the `user_id` in the select like `(data->'user_id')::uuid` but without luck.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The issue is that the -> operator returns JSON, which is why you get a string back with quotes as part of the string instead of the string you'd expect. See details in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html .

You should use the ->> operator instead as it will return an integer or text value. The returned text will not include the quotes. You can then cast the text to a uuid and Postgres will recognize it.

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d9e06/3/0

```
create table sessions (id integer, data json);
insert into sessions values(1, ' { "user_id": "bc2166dd-ca1d-41c6-9c66-610f844ca139" }');
create table users (id uuid, email text);
insert into users values('bc2166dd-ca1d-41c6-9c66-610f844ca139','a@b.com');

--query using ->> operator to return an integer or text instead of JSON
select (data->>'user_id')::uuid 
, * 
from sessions 
join users on (data->>'user_id')::uuid = users.id;
```