# Cast top-level JSONB field as UUID

Tags: postgresql

Consider a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  e uuid,
  v jsonb
)
```

I insert the following values:

```
INSERT INTO items (e, v) VALUES
  ('9a70439e-33c0-4b34-91f5-efac20b58301', '"92cb730c-8b4f-46ef-9925-4fab953694c6"'),
  ('92cb730c-8b4f-46ef-9925-4fab953694c6', '"Bob"'),
  ('92cb730c-8b4f-46ef-9925-4fab953694c6', '52');
```

Note how for `v`, I have actually stringified text and numbers -- *not* an object.

Now, what if I wanted to write a query like so:

```
WITH match AS (
  SELECT * FROM items WHERE e = '9a70439e-33c0-4b34-91f5-efac20b58301'
) SELECT * FROM items JOIN match ON match.v = items.e;
```

I would get:

```
Query Error: error: operator does not exist: jsonb = uuid
```

Is there a way I could tell postgres to "parse" the jsonb value, and see if it is a uuid?

I know about [Postgres cast to UUID from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53567903/postgres-cast-to-uuid-from-json) , where the `->>` operator was able to do the trick. But I can't do that in this case, because our json value is a strong not an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `->> 0` to extract the value as text:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE e = '9a70439e-33c0-4b34-91f5-efac20b58301'
  AND e::text = v ->> 0;
```

Comment: ->> 0 did the trick, thank you!